# Is this an accurate proof that no perfect square is of the form $4k+3$? ($k$ an integer)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, square-numbers

> A positive integer $n$ is a perfect square. Prove that it cannot be of the form $4k+3$, where $k$ is an integer.

I tried to prove this by proof by contradiction: if $n$ is a perfect square, then its square root, say $x$, is an integer. Suppose $n$ is of the form $4k+3$. Then $$x^2= 4k+3$$ which we can also write as $$x^2\equiv3 \mod 4$$ However, this congruence has no solutions. Therefore our initial assumption that $n$ is of the form $4k+3$ was false and $n$ cannot be of the form $4k+3$.

I know there's something missing or wrong in this proof but I don't know what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing missing, it is a very nice proof (note that in fact one can show that odd squares and congruent to $1$ mod $8$).

Comment: Can you explain how one would go about showing odd squares being congruent to 1 mod 8?Didn't get it.

Comment: Simply by writing $(2k+1)^2 = 4k^2 + 4k + 1 = 8\frac{k(k+1)}{2} + 1$ (note that the fraction is indeed an integer).

Comment: Nothing is proved as "this congruence has no solutions" is not justified.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That depends on the level one wants the proof. Any statement whose validity can be checked by testing a (small) finite number of cases need not usually be further justified.

Comment: @YvesDaoust can you explain how i should correct this proof?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: if you skip that part, the proof is completely void. "Any statement whose validity can be checked by testing a (small) finite number of cases need not usually be further justified.": your saying.

Comment: Obviously by proving that $x^2\equiv3\mod4$ is impossible.

Comment: That's it? So basically I've claimed that it has no solutions but haven't shown how and that's all what's missing?

Comment: That's 90% of the proof.

Comment: What you've done is trivial. What needs to be proved is your statement that the congruence has no solutions, as Yves points out.

Comment: @DavidMitra I disagree. Checking $4$ congruences is trivial. Getting the idea to work mod $4$ is the main thing.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: what $4$ congruences ? Two are enough. Leaving such "details" implicit is risky.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think that pointing out that "$n^2$ is not of the form $4k+3$" is equivalent to "the congruence $n^2\equiv 3\,\text{mod}4$ has no solutions" is certainly not the "intended proof" here.

Comment: Replacing $n=4k+3$ by $n\equiv3\mod 4$ is no great deal. The true idea is that the congruential equation can be solved by a finite case study, which is not evoked and even less made explicit. An allusion to the known properties of quadratic residues would have been a valid argument too, but my feeling is that such an answer to the exercise would get an F for laziness.

Comment: @Paradox101 The missing part just amounts to adding $0^2\equiv0\pmod{4}$, $1^2\equiv1\pmod{4}$, $2^2\equiv0\pmod{4}$, $3^2\equiv1\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @egreg: what's the use of checking for $2$ and $3$ ? $0$ and $1$ suffice. I believe in a confusion between $x\bmod4$ and $x^2\bmod4$. The devil is in the details.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Excluding $0$ and $2$ would require justification; not a long one, of course, but $2^2=4$ is shorter.

Comment: @egreg: excluding $0$ and $2$ will not work. And using with $x\mod 4$ deserves an explanation why this covers all cases for $x^2$. Yet another implicit assumption.

Answer (score 6):

For even $\sqrt n=2m$, $n=(2m)^2=4m^2\equiv\color{blue}0\mod 4$.

For odd $\sqrt n=2m+1$, $n=(2m+1)^2=4m^2+4m+1\equiv\color{blue}1\mod 4$.

So you never achieve congruency to $\color{blue}3$, as there are no other cases.

As a byproduct, this also establishes that $4k+2$ is never a perfect square.

Comment: Nice proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$4k+3$ is an odd number.
A square of an even number is even.
So the only candidates to have a square of the form $4k +3$ are 
$4a +1$ and $4a+3$.

Now $(4a+1)(4a+1) = 16a^2+8a+1$ and that is of the "form" $4k+1$.
Also $(4a+3)(4a+3) = 16 a^2 + 24a + 9 = 16 a^2 + 24 a + 8 + 1$ is of the form $4k+1$.

QED.

Answer (score 2):

Assume to the contrary that  there is integer $\ k$ such that $\ 4k+ 3$ is a perfect square

Let $\ x^2= 4k+3$

$\ 4k+3 = 2(2k+2)+1 \implies x^2$ is odd which follows $\ x$ is also odd

Then

Let $\ x= 2a+1$ for some integer $\ a$

Now we can write that  \begin{align} &x^2  = 4k+3\\
\implies &(2a+1)^2 =4k+3\\   
\implies &4a^2+4a+1 =      4k+3 \\
\implies &4a^2+4a-4k =       2 \\
\implies &4(a^2+a+k) =        2 \\
\implies &2(a^2+a+k)=        1 \\  
\end{align}     which is impossible since (a^2+a+k) is integer qed