# Can an integer of a particular form be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Can an integer of the form $27 + 72 n$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, be a perfect square? I just checked the first $100$ squares... would the quad residues be all the numbers relatively prime to $72$? So $27$ would be non residue.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you know what the quadratic residues modulo $72$ are?

Comment: I just checked the first 100 squares... would the quad residues be all the numbers relatively prime to 72? So 27 would be non residue

Comment: No, the residues are those numbers like $100\equiv 28\mod 72$, the values in the interval $[0,71]$ such that some number squares to that value.

Comment: Ok good call so I check and 27 is not a residue . Thank you

Comment: A quicker way to check this particular example is to note that $27+72n=9(3+8n)$, giving that $3+8n$ must be square.

Answer (score 7):

Consider $72n+27\pmod{4}$. First check that(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073150/is-this-an-accurate-proof-that-no-perfect-square-is-of-the-form-4k3-k-an?rq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1527479/579780) for proof), every square number can be of the form $4k,4k+1$. Hence, any square number $\pmod{4}$ have to be one of those forms. On the other hand $$72n+27\equiv 3\pmod{4}$$
Hence, there is no integer $n$ for which $72n+27$ is a square number.